# Connect the vertices of a geometry

Tags: three.js, blender

I imported in Three.js a `THREE.BufferGeometry` created in blender.
And I would like to move the vertices along normals with a custom shader ( more or less like that : http://codepen.io/yoanngueny/pen/FnxEl )

The problem is that all the faces are animated.
https://jsfiddle.net/hz4xv49g/1/

I tried to use `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` but it only works with `THREE.Geometry`.

I need `THREE.BufferGeometry` because I will apply specific parameter for each vertices ( attributes ) later and it seems that we can't do that for `THREE.Geometry` since r72.